# Использование шаблона в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите как использовать шаблон в Laravel?
К примеру, нужно чтобы меню было на всех страницах. Куда кинуть код с этой менюшкой и где указать данный шаблон?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Надо было в папку layouts кинуть шаблон, на нужных страницах указать `@extends("layouts.название шаблона")`